# Convert simple text to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to convert a string to XML. Of course I can do something like:

```
"<node Attribute1="att1">" + MyString + "</node>"
```

But why reinvent the wheel if there's something in .net for it. Is there a method that takes a node-name, attributes, and inner XML and returns an XML string?

Comment: cough, cough: XmlTextWriter. But its not better than your stuff... since start/end element has to be done by hand. Why not serialize your variable itself by c# framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387085.aspx)

```
var xElem = new XElement("node", new XAttribute("Attribute1", "att1"), "MyString");
var xml = xElem.ToString();
```

would give you

```
<node Attribute1="att1">MyString</node>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a XmlDocument object and use its LoadXmlMethod:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<node Attribute1=\"att1\">" + MyString + "</node>");
```